# R - Simulating data with loop

Tags: r, loops, repeat, simulate

I simulated data (1000 rows) following an exponential function with a mean of 120

```
  sim_data <- rexp(1000, 1/120)
```

How do I repeat this over 100 days to get the simulated data in a data frame like so:

head(sim_data_frame)

```
   sim_data1    sim_data2    sim_data3 ... sim_data100


 [1] 59.33708159  29.23829096  247.02014989  71.85972065
 [2] 14.03171085  46.64195945  38.03259199   92.18882163
...
 [1000]109.83320146 90.00037210   7.29312409   2.67249848
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `replicate` to do this `n` times

```
do.call(cbind, replicate(4, rexpr(1000, 1/120), simplify = FALSE))
```

Or use

```
replicate(4, rexpr(1000, 1/120))
```

Comment: I guess `replicate(4, rexp(10, 1/120), simplify = TRUE)` works the same :)

Comment: Yes, that was my initial answer, then didn't test it

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `matrix`

```
n <- 100
matrix(rexp(1000*n, 1/120),ncol = n)
```